# How can I increase the herou dyno count from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to dynamically increase and decrease the dyno count of my Heroku app. 
I read about the Heroku API https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference
and heroku vector but I was hoping for a simple gem.

I looked at other questions but none provided the line of code to this. 
Maybe by now there is a new gem that can make this simpler. 
Thank you

Comment: Looks like your on the right path, but don't like the complexity... Not much of a question. What you need is the Heroku API, it's the gem to communicate with Heroku in native Ruby.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Is a Ruby interface important? The Heroku CLI has a simple interface for scaling process counts if that's sufficient: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the **PlatformAPI** ruby client

The first step would be to authenticate via OAuth

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-oauth --app my-app-name
$ heroku authorizations:create -d "Platform API example token"
  Created OAuth authorization.
  ID:          2f01aac0-e9d3-4773-af4e-3e510aa006ca
  Description: Platform API example token
  Scope:       global
  Token:       e7dd6ad7-3c6a-411e-a2be-c9fe52ac7ed2
Next create a client instance
```

```
require 'platform-api'
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth('e7dd6ad7-3c6a-411e-a2be-c9fe52ac7ed2')
```

we can simply use

```
heroku.formation.update('APP_NAME', 'PROCESS_NAME', {'quantity' => 'QUANTITY'})
```

e.g.

```
heroku.formation.update('my-app-name', 'web', {'quantity' => '3'})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [PlatformAPI](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api) ruby client

The first step would be to authenticate via OAuth

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-oauth --app my-app-name
$ heroku authorizations:create -d "Platform API example token"
  Created OAuth authorization.
  ID:          2f01aac0-e9d3-4773-af4e-3e510aa006ca
  Description: Platform API example token
  Scope:       global
  Token:       e7dd6ad7-3c6a-411e-a2be-c9fe52ac7ed2
```

Next create a client instance

```
require 'platform-api'
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth('e7dd6ad7-3c6a-411e-a2be-c9fe52ac7ed2')
```

To view the number of dynos that the app currently have

```
dyno.list = PlatformAPI::Dyno.new(heroku)
dynos.list('my-app-name')
```

To create dynos

```
dyno.create(
  'my-app-name', 
  {command: "bundle exec unicorn_rails -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb -E $RACK_ENV"}
)
```

Modify `command` depending on the type of application you are running.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. But where do I choose the number of dynos that I want to have in my app?